# Text disappears in listview in android 2.3.6

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm using an inflated ListView in my project. The layout file is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background2" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the inflated layout file is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:src="@drawable/contact" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Large Text"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="Medium Text"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

            </LinearLayout>  
        </LinearLayout>   
    </LinearLayout>    
</LinearLayout>
```

The above code works fine when I'm using API level 11 or above, but below API level 11, it behaves in an awkward fashion, like the textView1 becomes totally invisible while textView2 is still visible. Also, while scrolling, all the items are VISIBLE but when the scrolling is finished, it again turns invisible. I'm using Actionbarsherlock. And yeah, one last thing, I'm using SearchView in actionbar, the bottom part of which strangely appears like a blue highlighted line in API 8 while everything works perfect in higher android levels

**EDIT**

This is my code snippet of ListView adapter

```
private class ContactViewHolder {
        CheckBox checkBox;
        TextView textView;
        TextView textView2;
        ImageView iv;
}

private class ContactArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact> {

        //private LayoutInflater inflater;
        List<Contact> myList;
        Context mContext;
        //Cursor cursor;

        public ContactArrayAdapter(Context context, List<Contact> planetList) {
            super(context, R.layout.simplerow, R.id.textView1, planetList);
            // Cache the LayoutInflate to avoid asking for a new one each time.
            //inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            mContext = context;
            myList = planetList;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            if(myList != null)
                return myList.size();
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Contact getItem(int position) {
            if(myList != null)
                return myList.get(position);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            if(myList != null)
                return myList.get(position).hashCode();
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // Contact to display

            ContactViewHolder holder;

            //If the listview does not have an xml layout ready set the layout
            if (convertView == null){

                //we need a new holder to hold the structure of the cell
                holder = new ContactViewHolder();

                //get the XML inflation service
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                //Inflate our xml cell to the convertView
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simplerow, null);

                //Get xml components into our holder class

                holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                holder.textView2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
                holder.iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

                holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                        Contact contact = (Contact) cb.getTag();
                        contact.setChecked(cb.isChecked());
                    }
                });

                //Attach our holder class to this particular cell
                convertView.setTag(holder);

            }else{

                //The listview cell is not empty and contains already components loaded, get the tagged holder
                holder = (ContactViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

            }

            //Fill our cell with data

            //get our person object from the list we passed to the adapter
            Contact contact = getItem(position);

            //Fill our view components with data
            holder.textView.setText(name1.get(position));
            holder.textView2.setText(num1.get(position));
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(contact.checked);

            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

The Contact class is

```
private static class Contact {
        private String name = "";
        private boolean checked = false;

        public Contact() {
        }

        public Contact(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public Contact(String name, boolean checked) {
            this.name = name;
            this.checked = checked;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public boolean isChecked() {
            return checked;
        }

        public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
            this.checked = checked;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }

        public void toggleChecked() {
            checked = !checked;
        }
    }
```

Comment: can u try to set the inflated relative layout height "android:layout_height="fill_parent" to warp_content ?

Comment: can you please provide code for your adapter? the problem may lay there

Comment: I've added the code...Plz check the revised question

Comment: yes im trying to locate the source of theis "while scrolling, all the items are VISIBLE but when the scrolling is finished, it again turns invisible. "

Comment: the adapter is wrong, im posting you a good adapter for your case

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to write a good adapater for your listview

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Person> {


Context context;
List<Person>myList;

public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Person> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);

    this.context = context;
    this.myList = objects;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    if(myList != null)
        return myList.size();
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Person getItem(int position) {
    if(myList != null)
        return myList.get(position);
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    if(myList != null)
        return myList.get(position).hashCode();
    return 0;

}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Holder holder;

    //If the listview does not have an xml layout ready set the layout
    if (convertView == null){

        //we need a new holder to hold the structure of the cell
        holder = new Holder();

        //get the XML inflation service
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        //Inflate our xml cell to the convertView
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.person_cell, null);

        //Get xml components into our holder class
        holder.txtName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.person_cell_txtName);
        holder.txtSurname = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.person_cell_txtSurname);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.person_cell_imageview);

        //Attach our holder class to this particular cell
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    }else{

        //The listview cell is not empty and contains already components loaded, get the tagged holder
        holder = (Holder)convertView.getTag();

    }

    //Fill our cell with data

    //get our person object from the list we passed to the adapter
    Person person = getItem(position);

    //Fill our view components with data
    holder.txtName.setText(person.getName());
    holder.txtSurname.setText(person.getSurname());

    Picasso.with(context).load(person.getImageUrl()).fit().into(holder.imageView);

    return convertView;
}

/**
 * This holder must replicate the components in the person_cell.xml
 * We have a textview for the name and the surname and an imageview for the picture
 */
private class Holder{

    TextView txtName;
    TextView txtSurname;
    ImageView imageView;

}
```

}

1. Notice that for Holder class you only set the properties reflecting the inflated xml. You dont need any constructor or getter/setters
2. In the get view you have to attach the holder class to the convertView tag property (convertView.setTag(holder))
3. retrieve the tagged holder if the convertView is not null

try to follow this pattern for the adapter

Comment: I really thank you for putting the efforts to solve my problem. I tried your code exactly as you said. But again sorry to tell you that still the same result is there. The textViews are still invisible :(

Comment: ok at least now you have the know how of a good custom adapter. Do you mind changing from RelativeLayout to Linear layout approach?

Comment: Okay.. Do I have to change both layouts (Main & inflated) or just the main layout??

Comment: I think I should become used to for saying the same line "Same result"...
Even after changing to LinearLayout

Comment: i posted revised inflated cell xml..can you pls check..if still wrong the inflated xml is correct..please post a screenshot of the problem and maybe i ask you for some more code

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:src="@drawable/contact" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="fill_vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tested with this xml as well. BUT....... :( 
Btw this is the screenshot of how the listview is looking : 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B53bgkJXIY2ua0FRWlQ4M2w1UGc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: its the data that is missing there...the components are there...you have the following options...loop through the list provided to the adapter and write down the data to the logcat...also provide your updated adapter so that i check it out

Comment: I've already done with printing the listview data to the logcat.... It was there with all the contents, and none of those was missing there... Btw I've updated my Java code for ArrayAdapter class... Check it out

Comment: you have to correct how you are filling the textviews....not name1.get(position)...you already got the contact object so do..holder.textView.setText(contact.name) ...can you post the contact class?

Comment: Okay... I'll post it tomorrow as it's too late for me now (1.15 am) and I need to wake up early in the morning... So going to bed now...  Gn

Comment: have a blessed rest :D

Comment: Thanks for the wish... Really had a blessed rest ;) And I've added the Contact class. And yeah, I think it shouldn't matter whether I'm using name1.get(position) or contact.name as they store the same values

Comment: Hello and Good Morning ! late night for me at the office..5 am here :D ...so..'name1' is never mentioned in the adapter class..I assume your adapter class is an inner class of the activity and name1 is a global variable...pls try change to holder.textView.setText(contact.getName());

Comment: I changed to textView.setText(contact.getName()) but as ususal, same result

Comment: Now this error is penetrating my head... Can't do anything except to wonder what could be the source of this silly bug..

Comment: Now I start to wonder too...if u want we arrange a remote session..or send me the project zipped

Comment: Else maybe post the while activity code since the adapter resides in it

Comment: Also lol..try to change to holder.textView.set text("work damn"); to check if its in contact list problem or in the layout...see if work damn appear in every row

Comment: The problem is not in activity.. Also, work damn doesn't appear in columns, i.e. it is also invisible as usual, but in android 2.3.6 only... In higher versions, as I said, there's no problem.... Also I figured out the cause but cannot eliminate the problem.... When using the default android theme, the listview was working fine, but after referencing it to actionbarsherlock, it stated this abnormal behavior..... But I need to use actionbarsherlock only as I've many things like SearchView, HomeAsUp, etc which doesn't support api 8 under the default theme

Comment: :/  this was a tough ride ..1 last tip ...gingerbread is only 7.4% of the market, I wouldn't bother much since till you are ready for deployment that figure will only go further down

Comment: and at least you now got the know how of a proper adapter :) (just to make feel a bit better)

Comment: Yeah that's right.... It may be a small share of gingerbread users but satisfaction of each and every user matters to me irresepective of the number... That's why I wanted to make it as better as possible for all versions of android..... Anyways, thank you so much for your precious time, help and efforts..... Btw I found a compromising way by launching a different activity without searchview and HomeAsUp button for API level < 11..... Though I would have been more happy if I had solved it using actiobarsherlock only and definitely would give a treat to that person who would solve this....

Comment: it was cool meeting you sir!, regarding getting every user happy trust me..you will never achieve that..android is a vast complicated network , even if you do everything 100% correct for any api , you will encounter problems with particular devices and manufacturers etc....good luck with your project!

Comment: I also realize that 100% satisfaction cannot be achieved, but still giving our best of the best can be achieved... So I just keep trying that... And thanks... Was nice meeting to you too :)